# TypeError:Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: angular, forms, typescript

I want to sum unit_price * quantity with one function but show this error.

My code ts:

```
 products: Products[];
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      'Quantity': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'Unit_price': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'Subtotal': new FormControl(this.Subtotal(), Validators.required),

    });

 Subtotal() {
   let subtotal = 0;
     for (let p of this.products) {
      subtotal = p.Unit_price * p.Quantity;
     }
     return subtotal;
   }
```

html code

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">

    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <input formControlName="Quantity" id="Quantity " type="number" class="validate" [(ngModel)]="Quantity">
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <input formControlName="Unit_price" id="Unit_price" type="number" class="validate" [(ngModel)]="Unit_price">
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
     <div class="c1" style="text-align:left;">
      Subtotal:
      <label for="total">Total {{Subtotal}} ALL</label>
       <input formControlName="Subtotal" id="Subtotal" type="number" class="validate" [value]="Subtotal"> 
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Can you help me please? I'm new web programmer.

Thank you

Comment: You have an array of products, but I do not see any loop in which you actually assign values to the array elements. Assuming you do that in some other part of code, you need to initialize the products array like this: products: Products[] = [].

Answer (score 0):

that is happened because you didn't initialize the products array

try this
`products: Products[] = [];`

Comment: Ok thnx, now my Subtotal is 0 all of time. Can you ?